# Creating an infinite-scroll of meteor collection in angular-meteor

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor, nginfinitescroll

I'm trying to enable infinite scroll for an angular-meteor app I'm working on that draws objects from a meteor/mongo collection.

I've adapted [step 12 of the angular-meteor tutorial](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_12) to use pagination for the app I'm working on, and now I'd like to convert to infinite scrolling.  I've been trying to adapt both the code from the tutorial and [this example from ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) for my purposes.

I imagine I'll need to use reactive variables, autorun, etc. similar to the tutorial, but I don't really know how to adapt it for infinite scroll. Considering the example below, how should I adjust my controller for it to use infinite scrolling, drawing from a database, with good angular-meteor practices for production?

**Demo ngInfiniteScroll HTML:**

```
  <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src='http://placehold.it/225x250&text={{image}}'>
  </div>
```

**Demo ngInfiniteScroll Function inside controller:**

```
$scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
$scope.loadMore = function() {
  var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
  for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    $scope.images.push(last + i);
  }
};
```

**My angular-meteor pagination code inside controller:**

```
$scope.page = 1;
$scope.perPage = 1;
$scope.sort = {'_id': -1};
$scope.orderProperty = '1';

$scope.images = $meteor.collection(function() {
  return Images.find({}, {
    sort : $scope.getReactively('sort')
  });
});

$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
  $meteor.subscribe('images', {
       limit: parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
       skip: (parseInt($scope.getReactively('page')) - 1) * parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
       sort: $scope.getReactively('sort')
     }).then(function(){
       $scope.imagesCount = $meteor.object(Counts ,'numberOfImages', false);        
  });
});

$scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
  $scope.page = newPage;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this basic example https://github.com/barbatus/ng-infinite-scroll.
Controller there re-subscribes every time onLoadMore is executed.

There is also a deployed demo http://ng-infinite-scroll.meteor.com.

Make sure this time `angular.module('infinite-scroll').value('THROTTLE_MILLISECONDS', 500)` is set properly (not very small) to avoid very frequent requests.

Comment: Wow, thank you for putting that together! It was much simpler to implement that I expected it would be, and I got my app to work on the first try following your basic example. I appreciate your help very much!